# dataframe to string for posting in a jira comment

Tags: python, jira

I am trying to create a string representation of a pandas DataFrame that can be formatted as a table in JIRA comments. My issue arises when newline characters (\n) in the string are not being correctly interpreted by JIRA, when I try to paste the string.

Code:
Here's the Python function I'm using to convert a DataFrame to a JIRA-formatted table string:

```
import pandas as pd

def dataframe_to_jira_string(df):
    jira_lines = []
    header = "||" + "||".join([f"*{col}*" for col in df.columns]) + "||"
    jira_lines.append(header)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        first_col = f"|{index}"
        other_cols = "|".join(row.astype(str).values)
        row_str = f"{first_col}|{other_cols}|"
        jira_lines.append(row_str)

    jira_table_string = "\n".join(jira_lines)
    return jira_table_string

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'CR': [4312, 1432, 7, 41, 1, 9, 11],
    'False': [13, 1, 7, 0, 30, 2, 4],
    'Miss': [5285, 250, 15, 45, 0, 57, 2],
    'True': [732, 48, 105, 19, 63, 10, 9]
}
index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

jira_table_string = dataframe_to_jira_string(df)
```

Question:
How can I ensure that the newline characters in the string are preserved and correctly interpreted by JIRA when pasted?
Is there a specific way I should format the string or handle newline characters in Python to make it compatible with JIRA's text processing?
Any advice or insights on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should first check JIRA documentation for `\n` - maybe it needs `\r\n` (like WIndows) or `\r` (like old Mac). Or maybe it needs HTML `<br/>`. OR like in Stackoverflow's editor you need two `\n` to start new paragraph, or you need two spaces at the end of line before `\n`

Comment: hey @furas, thanks.  checking https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=breaks it says use "\\" but when I use that instead of "\n" it doesn't work.  I also tried your suggestion <br/> and the others too

Comment: I don't use `JIRA` but I can only compare to `Stackoverflow`. In `Stackoverflow` you can use `new line` in question and answers but not in comments. Maybe they have the same.